# Does MongoDB support GIS geofencing with $geoWithin?

Tags: mongodb, geocoding, geospatial

I would like to have a MongoDB collection and each document contains a geospatial polygon defined by latitude/longitude points (in GeoJSON). Then, I would like to take any given longitude/latitude point and check if it resides within any of the MongoDB polygons defined in the documents. Hypothetically, this is what the documents would look like.

```
{
  "type" : "congressional",
  "points" : [ 
       { "coords" : [ 
            -141.0205, 
            70.0187 ] 
        }, 

        ...

        { "coords" : [ 
            -141.0205, 
            70.0187 ] 
        }  
    ]
}
```

Or maybe like so:

```
{ loc :
   { type : "Polygon" ,
     coordinates : [ [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 3 , 6 ] , [ 6 , 1 ] , [ 0 , 0 ] ] ]
} }
```

And then I would query it, hypothetically, like so (most likely with Mongo's `$geoWithin`):

```
db.places.find( { loc : { $geoWithin : { $geometry : "EACH DOCUMENT IN COLLECTION"} } } )
```

Is geofencing, or something similar, possible to do with the current MongoDB feature-set? If so, how would it be done?

Comment: I've completely reworded the question and included some hypothetical code examples in an effort to help clarify what I was asking. If you think this question is now formatted in a way that is easy to understand and clearly represents a real question, would you please consider voting to re-open it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 Good Question .. Have you been able to resolve this and what development language are you using ?

Comment: Based on all further research I've decided MongoDB doesn't really have support for geofencing. In the meantime, I've opted to use Postgres SQL with PostGIS. If MongoDB ever supports full geofencing I'd switch back to it. I hope that helps!

Comment: Mongo can do geoFencing, see answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to first find every document from the collection., and then make a "$geoWithin" query for every document, passing in the Polygon to test against for each case.

Depending on the number of documents in your collection, that may or may not provide sufficient performance.

Comment: Mongo does this all for you. See answer.

Comment: Note I answered the question in 2013.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but 'I believe you would have to first find every document from the collection' is not necessary, but let sleeping dogs ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has full support for geofencing or finding documents whose geometry intersects with a given geometry (point, polygon). The query below is an example. `geometry` of `Collection` is the field containing the geometry.

Document Example:

```
{     "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
               [
                  [
                     -74.001487,
                     40.692346
                  ],
                  [
                     -74.001755,
                     40.692057
                  ],
                  [
                     -74.000977,
                     40.691951
                  ],
                  [
                     -74.000827,
                     40.692297
                  ],
                  [
                     -74.001487,
                     40.692346
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
 }
```

JS Query:

```
//find quests bots that matches the users location
await Collection.find({     geometry:   
  { $geoIntersects: 
   { 
     {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [
        -73.99460599999999,
        40.7347229
        ]
      }
    } 
  }                         
});
```